# How to make TAR to not save the directory hierarchy

Tags: tar, ruby-on-rails

system("tar -czf #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export-result #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export")

When I decompress the resulting file I get

> app/c3ec2057-7d3a-40d9-9a9d-d5c3fe3ffd6f/home/tmp/export/and_the_files

I would like to just get:

> export_result/and_the_files

How do I change my TAR call to accomplish this?

solution:

> system("tar -czf #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export.tgz --directory=#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp export/")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it,

```
tar cfz target.tgz --directory=TARGET_DIR subdir_list
```

In your case it would look like,

```
tar cfz target.tgz --directory=app/c3ec2057-7d3a-40d9-9a9d-d5c3fe3ffd6f/home/tmp export/
```

Comment: So, first I specify where I want to save the result 'target.tgz' then I specify where the contents are and what subdirs should be removed. Correct?

Comment: This is an app hosted at Heroku, so the only place where I can write is RAILS_ROOT/tmp/ how do I write it so that target.tgz end up there?

Comment: I did it:  system("tar -czf #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export.tgz --directory=#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp export/")

Comment: right! Good for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change to `#{RAILS_ROOT}` before compression and don't specify it in the source files.